# Have Error while running REG QUERY command

Tags: cmd, registry

I'm trying to run the following reg query command :

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\A75706B3A4C812D409C77A28C9D8A93A\InstallProperties\DisplayVersion\2.0.0911"
```

Getting the following error and the reg key is present in the registry :

ERROR :

> The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value .